# How to use POST route as a middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

I have 2 routes

1. users.js `POST api/users`
2. auth.js   `POST api/auth/confirmation`

I want to use `auth/confirmation` as middleware in route `/users`

I have tried creating a temporary function and using `res.redirect(...)`
but it throws error `Cannot GET ....`

I can change the structure of the program to make it work, but I want to make it work this way by using another route as a middleware

**Temp function that I tried**

```java
    checkk = (req, res, next) => {

        console.log('middleware')
        res.redirect('api/auth/confirmation')
        next()
    }
```

**auth/auth.js**

```java
    router.post('/confirmation', (req,res)=>{
        //do something
    })
```

**/users.js**

```java
    router.post('/', auth.checkk, async (req, res) => {
        res.send("user route")
    })
```

**Exptected Output**

```
middleware
confirm route (If some error occurs it will go back with response)
user route
```

I dont want users to hit `/auth/confirmation` endpoint by themselves but via `/users`.

**Edit**

I am using `express-validator` to check req body, and I want the middleware to check that

```
router.post('/confirmation', [
    check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Enter valid email').isEmail(),
```

Comment: When you do `res.send()`, the server-client connection is ended there. So, you cannot add another route as a middleware. Instead, you have to create a simple express middleware that does its thing and calls the `next()` middleware.

Comment: sry I forgot about that, updated the question, is there any way i could achieve that functionality?

Comment: what does your /api/auth/confirmation route do?  Can you put whatever logic from it into your middleware function?

Comment: Don't complicate things. Just put that logic inside a middleware and add it into your routes.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use a route as middleware but instead a function. A common flow for your auth scenario is:

1. User makes request to access secure route `POST /users`
2. A first piece of middleware will set a user context e.g.:

```js
function setUserContext(req,res,next) {
    // get user from session or decode a JWT from auth header etc.
    if (user) {
        // user will be available for the lifetime of the request
        req.user = user
    }
    next()
}
```

Use this middleware across all routes: `app.use(setUserContext)`

3. A second middleware function can be applied to routes which need securing:

```js
function requireLoggedInUser(req,res,next) {
    if (req.user) {
        return next()
    }
    throw new Error("You need to be logged in")
}
```

Apply to the users route: `app.post('/users', requireLoggedInUser, (req, res) => { ... })`

In this case you wouldn't have the confirmation route but instead two middleware functions.